# QuickfixJ- Reset message seq numbers after Low msg seq error

Tags: quickfixj

I want to reset message sequence numbers  after Low Message Seq error.S the steps we did is :

1. In fromAdmin, after getting this error, we logout the session.
2. Now when the user logon with say reset checkbox click ,
   IN toAdmin,
   Checking, if it's logon message, and reset flag is true, then only

Session.lookupSession(sessionId).setNextSenderMsgSeqNum(1);
Session.lookupSession(sessionId).setNextTargetMsgSeqNum(1):

However, after this , I just got session created message on console,no logon nothing...

Let me know of I am missing something or any other approach

Comment: What about session.getStore().reset()?

Comment: Ok.. will try this. Thanks Christoph John.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working for me"? Those lines will definitely reset the message store.

Comment: Please upload the log somewhere and provide link.